# regular expression for checking US Address using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm developing an e-commerce website for a client. There is a task that requires me to verify if user inputs an US address (something like "2933 Glen Crow Court, San Jose, CA 95148") or not. This must be done in javascript code. I learned regular expression before but haven't used it for a long time. I wonder if anyone can give me a regular expression that suits what I need.

Comment: __"Give"__ you, no. __Help__ you, yes. What have you tried?

Comment: yes i have tried a lot regex examples from google search but none of them suits.

Comment: "something like "2933 Glen Crow Court, San Jose, CA 95148""? Something like? Is it like that or is it not? If you want a regular expression the first thing you need to determine is the *exact* pattern you need to match.

Comment: well i need something like
<number> <street name> (American style), <city/town>, <state> (only 2 characters) <postcode>

Comment: like example. 
2933 Glen Crow Court, San Jose, CA 95148

Comment: **1**. What's 'American Style'? **2**. When giving more info asked in the comments, please edit your question so that's it's clearer for everyone. **3**. Copy paste google examples is cool and all, but you should really try to write the regex yourself and come back when (if) it's not working. Your question will be clearer and you'll have more answers/enthusiastic welcome.

Comment: never mind. thanks anyway. I found a better way to validate the address without using annoying regular expression.

Comment: it turns out that I can check by verifying the data that Google map api returns. anyway, thank you all for your reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are in distress, help will be provided however it is advised that you show the attempt you have made before asking for information to be handed to you. From what I could get from your question, something along the follow regex would work:

```
/(\d+) ((\w+[ ,])+ ){2}([A-Z]){2} (\d){5}/
```

#### Breakdown

```
1) (\d+) - Match any number of digits at the start
2) ((\w+[ ,])+ ){2} - Match any alphanumeric characters followed by a space or a comma, exactly twice (once for street, once for city)
3) ([A-Z]){2} - Match 2 capital letters
4) (\d){5} - Match five digits
```

#### Demo

http://regex101.com/r/uU2wT7

Comment: @php.dev.2014, If my answer was helpful, would you mind accepting it? Thanks

Comment: Can u show me how to accept it pls? I saw the vote button but when I pressed it, it says I must have 15 reputation points.